# sqlzoo SELECT within SELECT #8

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not exactly sure how to do this question I know I need to use the previous method taught with #7 but I don't how to approach it to take alphabetically if it was a number it would be easy enough.

Maybe use a `LIKE` or `BETWEEN` clause?

```
SELECT continent, name FROM world x
  WHERE name ALL
    (SELECT name FROM world y
        WHERE name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT continent, name FROM world x
 WHERE name =
(SELECT name FROM world y
WHERE y.continent=x.continent
order by name limit 1)
```

order by and then select the top 1

Answer (score 0):

Just happen to solve the same problem..
this happens to be frustrating at times when the logic is right but it shows error and you can not figure out what's wrong

anyways... this i guess is the answer

```
SELECT x.continent, x.name FROM world x
WHERE x.name in (SELECT y.name FROM world y
               WHERE y.continent like x.continent
               order by y.name 
               limit 1)
```

it is similar to [@Kieran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51078187/19617537) mentioned above but some difference

However in my case it happens so that this answer was giving error
so with some logic of group by ,
this can also work

```
select x.continent, x.name from world x 
where x.name in ( select min(y.name) from world y 
                   where y.continent like x.continent 
                   group by y.continent)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).